# Overwrite of CSV file via jmeter

Tags: jmeter

we are able to write dropdown of a needed variable of matchNr case to multiple CSV file's in setup thread group with the below code

```
def cnt = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("value_matchNr"));
for(int i=1; i<=cnt; i++)
{
    def File f =new File('C:/INPUT/value.csv');
    f<<vars.get("value_"+i) << '\n';
}
```

i am not able to delete created files via batch file as it saying file got using in the backend, so i need to delete the contents of created files.

please help on this scenario, to overwrite

Batch file1: to delete csv files

echo
del "C:\Data*.csv" /s /f /q
echo Done!!

CMD used in jsr2253 sampler:
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /c C:/DeleteInput.bat");

Answer (score 0):

If the file is being used in CSV Data Set Config you won't be able to delete it.

You can try removing the file somewhere in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) using the following Groovy code invoking [File.delete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--) function :

```
new File('input.csv').delete()
```

if it fails (although shouldn't) you can consider using [File.deleteOnExit()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit--) function instead

Quick test shows that the file created in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) and accessed in the "normal" Thread Group can be deleted without issues in the tearDown Thread Group:

[image]

---

If you want just to remove content you can call the following command:

```
new File('input.csv').text = ''
```